# Multiple require() from the same library in the same module

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules, commonjs, slack-api

I'm looking at the sources of the [@slack/client npm package for NodeJs](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/master/lib/models/model.js) and see that right at the top they have this:

```
var forEach = require('lodash').forEach;
var bind = require('lodash').bind;
var has = require('lodash').has;
var isArray = require('lodash').isArray;
var isEmpty = require('lodash').isEmpty;
var isObject = require('lodash').isObject;
```

What's the point in cherry picking all this from the lodash module when you can make it more succinct by only including the whole lib once and then using the methods you need?

```
// Include the whole lib
var _ = require('lodash');

// And later
if (_.isObject(...)) // etc
```

It's not like they are using each method many times. In fact, most are used just once or twice. Also, it is my understanding that even when partially requiring part of a module, the whole thing is `eval()`'d, so there is no advantage memory or performance-wise.

I find this package to be very well written so I'm curious to know why they chose to do this.

Comment: If you only need a few functions from lodash then why include the entire library? I guess that would be the point. That being said it might be down to better understanding the code, you can see easily what is being used from lodash, find and replace with pure js solutions eventually?